# Профиль пользователя в базе данных

Tags: php, mysql

При создании (учебного) сайта знакомств столкнулся с такой проблемой. Профиль зарегистрированного и вошедшего на сайт пользователя находится в базе данных. Пользователь обновляет страницу сайта несколько раз в минуту. И что — постоянно делать запрос к базе данных для отображения его ника, статуса, фотографии и т. д.? 
Не будет ли это накладно для самой базы данных? Или целесообразнее изначально поместить все данные в массив `$_SESSION`? Как тогда быть с фотографией?

Comment: потом прикрутите memcache.

Comment: Спасибо, более чем лаконично! Для того и существует база данных!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаете, что я Вам скажу.

Я раньше, лет в 16 писал один сайт на PHP + MySQL - заодно изучал это дело. Я писал этот сайт очень-очень долго. Знаете почему? Потому, что я пытался сделать всё и сразу. Это не правильно! Сделайте основной функционал, сделайте так, чтобы всё работало и потом оптимизируйте. Этот запрос в данный момент Вам никак не сможет испортить картину.

Я в данный момент занимаюсь разработкой небольшой социальной сети, которую хочу выпустить в люди и у меня там всё так и работает. Сессии реализованы на БД, а это два запроса (запрос сессий + обновление по завершению работы скрипта) + обновление строки юзера (время последнего посещения + ссылка на последнюю страницу).

Я же по своему опыту уже не собираюсь заниматься мелочами которые мне в данный момент не нужны - это трата драгоценного времени. Я понимаю, что мой сайт ляжет, если на него нормально выдать запросов. Но я не делаю ничего для того чтобы исправить это в данный момент - решайте проблемы по мере их поступления.

Делайте то, что действительно необходимо сейчас! Я не говорю, что нужно писать плохой код. Пишите код и держите в уме, что будете его оптимизировать, пишите комментарии в трудных алгоритмах - потом Вы забудете это, но если оно Вам понадобится - комментарии помогут — это тоже опыт.

Я не против Вашего вопроса, он логичен, он необходим чтобы получить вот такой ответ.

Кстати, сессии это тоже нагрузка, только в Вашем случае — на файловую систему.

:)

---

**Это [комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/181426#181454) к ответу от @[Alexandr Vasilenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10825/alexandr-vasilenko).** Просто не поместился, а сказать это необходимо!

---

Уххх, ребят.

Создаем каталог с аватарами (`/avatars`) в котором будут находится подкаталоги, далее нам нужно хранить по 10 000 аватаров в одном из каталогов.

При загрузке аватара в зависимости от User ID (далее - `uid`) выбираем необходимый каталог.

Если `uid <= 10000` значит - `/avatars/1`, если `uid > 10000 and uid <= 20000 значит`/avatars/2` и так далее.

При загрузке аватара создаем любой хеш примерно 8 символом и записываем его в базу, в таблицу юзеров.

**Почему хеш?**

— потому что опера (не только опера скорее всего) кеширует все изображения, если указать в названии аватара uid, то при обновлении аватара необходимо обновлять страницу через F5 — это не правильно.

**А если у меня несколько размеров одного аватара?**

— в промежуточном каталоге (`/avatars/(промежуточный каталог)`) создаем каталоги 1, 2, 3 в зависимости от количества копий и размеров аватара.
то есть, получится - `/avatars/1/2/sd3wn843n.jpg` - 200x200 аватар пользователя с uid < 10000 и hash sd3wn843n

**Это же сложновато будет вытаскивать аватары.**

— создаем функцию которая выводит ссылку рассчитывая промежуточный каталог

Comment: 10 тысяч на каталог - IMHO, многовато. Для оценки можно насоздавать столько пустых файлов и посмотреть, как шустро будет отрабатывать ls, например. Если с задержкой, то это много.

Comment: 10000 — это не константа!

Comment: Собственно, я и предлагаю вообще не заморачиваться с вычислением каталога по id, а использовать 1 или 2 символа хэша: s/d/3wn843n для sd3wn843n, например. Никаких лишних операций и никакого переполнения корневого каталога: 33 на первом уровне обеспечат ненапряжное распределение минимум для 33 тысяч файлов (по тысяче на каталог), а два уровня уже для миллиона и больше.

Comment: Так тоже возможно.

Answer (score -1):

Конечно помещайте все в сессии, а насчет картинки - храните в сессии ссылку на уменьшенную копию картинки, главное при обновлении профиля, не забывайте обновлять информацию в сессиях!

Comment: А с практической точки зрения? На сайте, допустим, зарегистировано 2000 человек. Получается помимо каталога каталогов с фотоальбомами необходимо   создать еще каталог с уменьшенными фото профиля?

Comment: Ну и что такого? Всё равно это лучше, чем отдавать из БД. Если файлов будет много, имеет смысл разнести их по вложенным каталогам. Например, если имя файла - это ID юзера, то создать подкаталоги с именами 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 и сохранять так (при имени, например, "1234.png"): avatars/1/234.png. Имена 1.png-9.png хранить в корне :) Ну или как-то ещё, в любом случае больше нескольких сотен файлов в одном каталоге я бы хранить не стал.

Comment: Круто. Да - лучше пару слов на форуме, нежели полкниги программиста-фантаста.))

Comment: @klopp ага, и будет 2000 папок :) Я бы привязывал папки юзеров к определенному промежутку времени. И 1000 файлов в одной директории вполне нормально.

Comment: Откуда 2000 папок? Только 10. А если сделать 2 уровня, то 10x10 хватит уж точно. Впрочем, как - дело хозяйское, как и 1000 файлов в каталоге.

Comment: @klopp у вас как получается из ответа: 

> если имя файла - это ID юзера, то создать подкаталоги с именами 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

то имея 2000 юзеров, будет и 2000 папок.

Comment: @lampa, и дальше написано: для ID 1234 - /1/234.png, 1-9 в корне (то есть по первому символу). Я когда-то для хранения большого кол-ва файлов использовал даты, вида yyyy/mm/dd, но плюнул. Куда проще работать с каталогами вида "a/b/cdefg", где "abcdefg" - что-то уникальное для каждого файла, md5 или ID. Вот прямо сейчас в одном проекте под такой схемой живёт за 10 тысяч файлов и ничего :)

Comment: У меня по датированию живет фотохостинг :) хешируется год и месяц как уникальное значение. В каждом таком каталоге еще папки по дням, естессно тоже захешированы.

Comment: Хорошо, а где вы тогда собираетесь хранить остальные картинки ? Ведь это сайт знакомств, и там у каждого будет полно фоток? А в прочем какая разница, минус уже все-равно поставили, храните и остальные фото в бд, может тогда ваш сайт ляжет в разы быстрее!!! И еще, почитайте о файловых серверах...

Comment: @Alexandr Vasilenko, это о чём вообще? Все и так говорят, что хранить надо файлы. А минус, думаю, влепили за гениальную идею "хранить в сессии ссылку на уменьшенную копию" :)

Comment: Я не мог это не написать! Читайте [**тут**][1]!

[1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/181426#181532